# Outputing Different Number of Pin Depending on the Input

Tags: led, integrated-circuit

Im tying to build a little meter type display on my arduino using this 10 bar LED display thing.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07BJ8FDT4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BJ8FDT4)

However the problem I'm running to is that I dont have 10 pins to spare to control each of the LED individually. From looking around I think a IC chip might be my best option. But im not sure is there one that output an increasing number of pins depending on a voltage of a single input pin? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Most common solutions are: use a [shift register](https://docs.onion.io/omega2-arduino-dock-starter-kit/arduino-kit-shift-register.html), [multiplexing](https://www.instructables.com/LED-Multiplexing-101-6-and-16-RGB-LEDs-With-Just-a/) and [Charlieplexing](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/LiLShReDdeR/charlieplexing-with-arduino-5b4ade). You can also use an IO expander IC or an "LED display driver" IC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ErikR noted, you only need 4 GPIO's to control up to 12 LEDs using a technique known as [charlieplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO8PT2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To turn on LED D9

```
pinMode(0, INPUT); // tristate as not used
pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(2, INPUT);
pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
```

In real code you'd use some suitable data structures to avoid the code repetition the above implies.

Some examples

- [Charlieplexing Arduino - Controlling 12 LEDs with 4 GPIO Pins](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/charlieplexing-arduino-to-control-12-leds-with-4-gpio-pins)
- [Twelve PWM Outputs from an ATtiny85](http://www.technoblogy.com/show?2H0K)

The second example is more advanced but could be used if you want multiple LEDs illuminated at the same time (bar vs spot graph).

Answer (score 4):

Actually chips that can drive bar graph LEDs based on input voltage do exist. They are called bar display drivers so you can search for them.

Comment: The most well-known of this kind of chip is perhaps the LM3914.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a shift register like the SN74HC595 [SN74HC595](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scls041i/scls041i.pdf?ts=1623164303497&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) to expand your port numbers.